# Make 0 add to 1 over a specified time

Tags: arithmetic

I have the number 0, and every 1/30th of a second, I want to add some number to 0 in order to make it 1 in a specified amount of time. My question is, how do I find the number that should be added to 0 every 1/30th of a second?

For example, if the amount of take it should take for it to add to 1 is 0.1 seconds, you would need to add some number to 0 three times (because 0.1/(1/30) is 3). Again, my problem is that I do not know which number to add to 0 to achieve an end value of 1 after 0.1 seconds.

I've tried doing this every 1/30th of a second:
x = specifiedtime/(1/30)
y = 1/x
0 + y

Any other ideas will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add to $1$ after $t$ seconds you need to add $\frac {30}t$ every $\frac 1{30}$ seconds.  If $t=1$ this is $\frac 1{30}$.  If $t=0.1$ this is $\frac 13$.  This works perfectly if $t$ is a multiple of $\frac 1{30}$ second.  If not, there are rounding errors.  For the first, round $t$ down to the nearest multiple of $\frac 1{30}$